# Java. lang out of memory

Tags: java, matlab, memory

I ran a script on MATLAB and it worked fine, when i want to run the script again, then MATLAB stuck in busy! i found a file "hs_err_pid1124" in the directory i works in it contain the following:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 16384000 bytes for GrET in  
C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_17\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp. Out of swap  
space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=1124, tid=1380
#  Error: GrET in 
C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_17\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp
#
# JRE version: 6.0_17-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.3-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )

. 
.
.
```

My computer RAM is 4G, i increased the System Swap Space, but still the problem not solved!!

Thanks,

Comment: The above error message doesn't really tell us much, seeing your script would be more helpful. Also, if it worked once and then failed the second time this would suggest either a memory leak, or that the second time you had used more memory in the workspace before running the script (e.g.: the results of the first execution).

Comment: well, i didn't running any thing on the computer, only run the script, and i ran it on another computer many times without any problem.

Comment: yes, it seems memory leak, but how to solve it!

Comment: Could you show us your code? Else we can not know what is causing the issue.

Comment: well it's long, but the following is a summary for it:

do the folloing many times :
 -   create configuration file
 -   call a simulator to run the configuration file..
 -   a stat file will be created from the simulator
 -   parse the stat file .. and take some information and write it on atext file ... 

note: i cleared all the vraibles, close all the opened files, and write into text file instead of arrays to save memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely suspect here is your code. I would expect you to do something strange (opening a file, and not closing it later?! Reading each file into a continiously growing variable?!).

However, without code this is hard to diagnose.

Here is what you can do:

1. Evaluate the visible memory usage: Put a breakpoint somewhere halfway through, and inspect the size of the largest variables. Also check the total size. (If the error is a regular matlab error, you could also use `dbstop if error`)
2. Persuade matlab to release memory: If step 1 yields nothing, you may actually be doing things right, but perhaps matlab does not manage its memory properly. This is rare, but occurs sometimes when repeating simple tasks a lot of times. In this case you can place the `pack` command somewhere in your code. Probably it will help.